# Looping over a templated C++ function with int type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++20

Is there a solution like this to loop over a function with a templated int parameter that doesn't require creating a new struct with a `body()` function any time `forIdx` is needed with a new function? Templated lambdas in C++20 seemed promising, but it didn't seem possible to specify template parameters that aren't automatically deduced.

```
struct LoopFunc {
    template <int i>
    void body() {
        std::cout << i;
    };
};

template<int i>
struct forIdx {
    template<typename T>
    static void loop(T&& func) {
        func.body<i>();
        forIdx<i - 1>::loop(func);
    }
};

template<>
struct forIdx<-1> {
    template<typename T>
    static void loop(T&& func) {};
};

int main() {
    forIdx<10>::template loop(LoopFunc{});
}
```

The function is used to create a cartesian product of tuple elements. `DirectProduct` contains elements that all have a static `generateAllElements()` function.

```
    struct CrossProduct {
        std::tuple<MockElement...> vals;
        std::set<DirectProduct> result;
        template <int num>
        void body() {
            if (result.empty()) {
                for (const auto& e2 : std::get<num>(vals).generateAllElements()) {
                    DirectProduct tmp;
                    std::get<num>(tmp.vals) = e2;
                    result.insert(tmp);
                }
            }
            else for (const DirectProduct& e1 : result)
                for (const auto& e2 : std::get<num>(vals).generateAllElements()) {
                    DirectProduct tmp = e1;
                    std::get<num>(tmp.vals) = e2;
                    result.insert(tmp);
                }
        };
    };
```

`DirectProduct` uses the `CrossProduct` in its own `generateAllElements()` function

```
    std::set<DirectProduct> generateAllElements() const {
        CrossProduct crossProduct{ };
        forIdx<std::tuple_size<std::tuple<MockElement...>>::value - 1>::template loop(crossProduct);
        return crossProduct.result;
    };
```

Comment: Don't `constexpr` or `consteval` functions suited for your needs?

Comment: The actual use of forIdx needs the function to be void, but it also does need data from the function it is called in, so I actually don't know if what I'm trying can be done without a struct or some kind of lambda.

Comment: The solution I provided seems to answer your question, but your comment suggests that there may be some additional constraints that are not apparent from the shown code. If so, please edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: It's to create a cartesian product of tuple elements, I was able to loop over elements of the tuple simply enough, but accessing and modifying specific indices of the tuple when there could be repeated types was the problem

Comment: Then this is an XY problem, i.e. the problem you want to solve is different than the one you've asked. As I said, please edit the question to make it clear what you want to achieve; you haven't mentioned anything about cross products, or tuples, or different types at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Templated lambdas in C++20" have you said?

Do you mean something as follows?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t I>
void loop_func()
 { std::cout << I << ' '; };

int main ()
 {
    []<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    { (loop_func<sizeof...(Is)-Is-1u>(), ...); }
    (std::make_index_sequence<11u>{});
 }
```

That prints

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty much what I wanted, thank you

Comment: @JoyMcGibbon The best way of saying just that is to actually accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, new to this

Answer (score 1):

```
template<auto x>
using value_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>,x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr value_t<x> value={};
template<std::size_t...Is>
using indexes_t=std::tuple<value_t<Is>...>;
template<std::size_t>
constexpr indexes_t<Is...> indexes={};
```

some compile time values.

```
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto indexes_upto=[]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){ return indexes<Is...>; }( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
```

now we are almost done.

```
void do_foreach_arg(auto f){
  return [&](auto&&...args){
    ((void)(f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args))),...);
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto do_foreach_index_upto( auto f ){
  std::apply( do_foreach_arg(std::move(f)), indexes_upto<N> );
}
```

your main now looks like

```
do_foreach_index_upto<N>([](auto I){ LoopFunc{}.body<I>(); });
```

but the `LoopFunc` class is really not needed.  You can just call `some_func<I>()` directly.

What we do here is we make stateless compile time values representing the integers up to 10.  We stuff them in a tuple, unpack them with std apply, and unpack that with `do_foreach_arg`.

We could probably skip the tuple "step" here, but more advanced use could find it useful.